# Help decoding bus signalling

Tags: rs485

I'm trying to decode a RS485 bus from an alarm system.  If I connect it to a computer on baud 3600 then I receive ASCII strings which match what is being shown on the alarm panel; however, when I look at the signalling from the microcontroller to the line driver, this is what I see:

[image]

The period between the two gray dotted lines is 2ms.  It looks more like manchester encoding to me, or otherwise there are too many bits and the pulse widths vary irregularly from what I can see.

Is anyone able to help me with what is going on?  It decodes ascii strings with a PC uart converter, but I'm trying to identify the characters that start and end the packets so I need to be able to read the trace but I am perhaps decoding it incorrectly?

I read it as 1001001001011011010010, which is more than 8 bits.  The widths of the smaller pulses are akin to 9600bps but I cannot understand why I am receiving usable ascii at 3600bps.

Comment: What chip is that? Are you sure you're actually using 3600 baud?

Comment: It is an FT232 ordinary serial-USB converter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an UART at 9600 baud, 8N1, this decodes to four bytes:

```
0 10001000 1 0 00101111 1 0 11111110 1 0 00001100 1

  0x11         0xF4         0x7F         0x30
```

Apparently, that chip is more than a simple line driver.

Comment: Hi.  Thanks that's the exact decoding I'm seeing at 3600...

Comment: Thanks this looks like the correct solution, it is 9600bps UART.  not sure what's happened my end - will have another look..   Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have parity bits in the transmission (or maybe some extra ninth bit): -

[image]

The red arrows show the start bit positions so your payload data looks to me like: -

10010010

11110111

10001100

P = Parity (ninth bit) S = Stop

It's not Manchester encoded else the idle period would be 101010101 etc..

Comment: The parity values do not appear to be correct.

Comment: If it isn't a parity bit (and I take your point) then maybe it is some ninth bit that means something else?

Comment: On RS485 I use the 9th bit set to indicate the start of a packet, possibly they use 9th bit clear to indicate the start.

Comment: I know some UARTS support a 9th bit and have seen it used to indicate the other 8 bits are for the address being accessed.

Comment: That's not a parity bit, it's a stop bit.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast how come in what I reckon is the first byte, that bit is zero then? If it were a stop bit it would be 1.

Comment: You've mis-divided the trace. The low periods (the first 3) are simply too wide to be taken as two zeroes - they are 3. So the first byte is 10001000, followed by a stop bit and then a start bit. As a result, your start bit locations are badly off after the first one.  Furthermore, your bit identificatiion gives about 30 bits in 4 msec, for a very non-standard baud rate of 7500 (or so) baud). CL's answer is the correct transcription.

Comment: I did line stuff up in "paint" to make the best fit but I take your point. The op has accepted the other answer and he states it is right yet, in his question he stated there were two zeroes following the initial 1. There were no other answers when I gave my answer so I gave it in full honesty. Saying I've misdivided the trace is easily said in retrospect!

Comment: @andyaka thanks for your input Andy, I made an error it seems somewhere - so sorry my question was incorrect.  thanks for yours and the other's input - I very much appreciate it.

Comment: @gho No problem dude, seems like you got an answer that was correct and that's all the really matters.